# Spring data mongo filter by difference in value of 2 fields

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a document like following

```
Document {
   BigDecimal originalPrice
   BigDecimal discounPrice
}
```

Now i want to get results where the result of`[originalPrice - discountPrice]` is from biggest difference to smallest difference in a paginated manner.

Is there a way to achieve this using spring data mongodb without having to save the difference in a 3rd field and than query the third column ?

Update:

Based on @HbnKing answer i tried the following using spring-data-mongodb but now i get error

```
ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = project("originalPrice", "discountPrice").and(Subtract.valueOf("originalPrice")
                .subtract("discountPrice"))
                .as("diff");
SortOperation sortOperation = sort(new Sort(Direction.DESC, "diff"));

TypedAggregation<ProductVariantModel> aggregation = Aggregation
                .newAggregation(ProductVariantModel.class, projectionOperation, sortOperation, skip((long) pageable.getOffset()), limit((long) pageable.getPageSize()));
```

Error:

> Command failed with error 16556 (Location16556): 'cant $subtract
>   astring from a string' on server

Comment: I'm not sure that spring data will run it but you can (with the cost of having a server dependency) write and save your query in the server [Link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) and call it from @Query. It's  just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

yes  . you can use `$subtract`  to  compute the differ  with  your data then   `$sort`

in mongo shell it looks  like this

```
Enterprise repl2:PRIMARY> db.wang.aggregate([{ $project: { a: 1, b:1, differ: { $subtract: [ "$a", "$b" ] } } },{$sort :{differ:-1}} ] )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d494045fd02abc31f622366"), "a" : 100, "b" : 30, "differ" : 70 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d494062fd02abc31f622368"), "a" : 13, "b" : 7, "differ" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d49406afd02abc31f622369"), "a" : 13, "b" : 9, "differ" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d494058fd02abc31f622367"), "a" : 10, "b" : 7, "differ" : 3 }
MongoDB Enterprise repl2:PRIMARY> db.wang.find()  
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d494045fd02abc31f622366"), "a" : 100, "b" : 30 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d494058fd02abc31f622367"), "a" : 10, "b" : 7 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d494062fd02abc31f622368"), "a" : 13, "b" : 7 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d49406afd02abc31f622369"), "a" : 13, "b" : 9 }
MongoDB Enterprise repl2:PRIMARY>
```

I will give  you a java demo later
Edit

```
 AggregateIterable<Document> aggregate = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.project(fields(include("a", "b"),
                new BasicDBObject("differ",new BasicDBObject("$subtract",Arrays.asList("$a","$b"))))),
                Aggregates.sort(new BasicDBObject("differ",-1)),
                Aggregates.project(fields(include("a","b")))));
        MongoCursor<Document> iterator = aggregate.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
```

Edit  for your error

Prefix the field with a `$`  when use `Subtract`   .

```
Subtract.valueOf("$originalPrice")
                .subtract("$discountPrice"))
                .as("diff");
```

you'd better  show your `spring-data-mongodb` version

Comment: Nice! The goal is to use Spring Data @Query (to get pagination). Hope it will accept it.

Comment: yes  @Query  is like the mongo shell  it  should  extends  the `MongoRepository`

Comment: it  was  caused  by  your fieldname  miss  `$` .   let  me  check  it

Comment: @HbnKing 2.1.6.RELEASE spring data mongodb

Comment: @HbnKing - Adding $ has no effect. I assume this has something to do with the field itself. Since the field is BigDecimal which mongo stores as String may be causing the issue. Not sure though.

Comment: @ Saurabh kumar    `BigDecimal`  or `Decimal128 `   they  are not the same !   you  mean  it  stores  as String  ?   give me   more  message

Comment: show the data format again . try  use `$convert `  to  change your  ` price`  to  `Num`